# Instagram doesn't take my Picture through Selenium

Tags: java, android-studio, selenium-webdriver, instagram

**1. Project:** Trying to make a repost app with Selenium and Java in Android Studio

- System: MacOS 11.6.6
- Driver: ChromeDriver 102.0.5005.61
- Programming Language: Java
- IDE: Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1

**2. Code**:

`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

```
public static <i> void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",         "/Users/johannes/Downloads/chromedriver-2");
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?hl=en&source=auth_switcher");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    driver.findElement(By.className("HoLwm")).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("username")));
    driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("//yourusername");
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("//yourpassword");
    // Variablen Einfügen ->
    new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type='submit']"));
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
    String url = ("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?hl=en&source=auth_switcher");
    String currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    while (url == currentURL) {
        WebElement elementz = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type='submit']"));
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elementz);
    }
    new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    WebElement Nichtjetzt = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[text()='Not Now']")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(
            webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
    WebDriverWait waitt = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    WebElement NichtjetzT = waitt.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[text()='Not Now']")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(
            webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
    NichtjetzT.click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    WebDriverWait waits = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    WebElement Nichtjetztz = waits.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[text()='Jetzt nicht']")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(
            webDriver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
    Nichtjetztz.click();
    // Variable Einfügen ->
    String Suche = "designatgarten";
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Suchen']")).sendKeys(Suche);
    new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("-qQT3")));
    driver.findElement(By.className("-qQT3")).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#react-root > section > main > div > div.fx7hk > a._9VEo1.T-jvg > span > span")));
    url = "https://www.instagram.com";
    driver.getCurrentUrl();
    if (!currentURL.equals(url)) {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        try {
            long lastHeight = ((Number) js.executeScript("return document.body.scrollHeight")).longValue();
            while (true) {
                ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");
                Thread.sleep(2000);

                long newHeight = ((Number) js.executeScript("return document.body.scrollHeight")).longValue();
                if (newHeight == lastHeight) {
                    break;
                }
                lastHeight = newHeight;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    List<WebElement> srcList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("img"));
    srcList.stream().filter(sa -> sa.getAttribute("src").startsWith("cdninstagram.com"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    WebElement removedStr = srcList.remove(0);
    WebElement removedStr2 = srcList.remove(srcList.size()-1);
    WebElement removedStr3 = srcList.remove(srcList.size()-1);
    System.out.printf("Found %s links to images\n", srcList.size());
    for (WebElement sa : srcList) {
        System.out.println("[" + sa.getAttribute("src") + "]");
        //Lösung entfernen von Highlights



    }

    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(WebElement e : srcList){
        strings.add(e.getAttribute("src"));
    }
    int n = 0;


    String LetztesFoto;
    String LetztesElement = strings.get(strings.size()-1 + n);
    LetztesFoto = LetztesElement;
    try(InputStream in = new URL(LetztesFoto).openStream()){
        Files.copy(in, Paths.get("/Users/johannes/AndroidStudioProjects/InstagramRepost/app/src/main/java/com/example/image.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    n -= 1;

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#react-root > section > nav > div._8MQSO.Cx7Bp > div > div > div.ctQZg.KtFt3 > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > button > div > svg")).click();
    WebElement currentElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=file]"));
        currentElement.sendKeys("/Users/johannes/AndroidStudioProjects/InstagramRepost/app/src/main/java/com/example/image.jpg");


    }
    }`
```

**3. Problem:** If I run the code on Android Studio it shows no errors that it has failed or anything **but** Instagram seems to have got the Photo or at least it has got something because after the code is finished it reloads the page and brings me back to the mainpage"

**4. Problematic Part:** In my opinion this part of the code:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#react-root > section > nav > div._8MQSO.Cx7Bp > div > div > div.ctQZg.KtFt3 > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > button > div > svg")).click();
        WebElement currentElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=file]"));
            currentElement.sendKeys("/Users/johannes/AndroidStudioProjects/InstagramRepost/app/src/main/java/com/example/image.jpg");
```

Causes the problem somewhere. I think it is likely caused by the Absolute Path above.

**5. Already tried Approaches :**

- `input[@type='file']`
- `input[@accept = 'image/jpeg']`
  Both of them caused an error in Android Studio
- Changing the Download Location from a folder on my desktop to the folder where the main activity is

Comment: Have the browser show the network tab of the developer tools and inspect what the browser is actually uploading to instagram. Compare this to what you get if you do this by hand in a browser.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker I tried using this but Chrome showed me nothing special about the actions, but if I upload it by hand chrome gives me a blob , I don't know if you know what that means but it says blob:https://www.instagram.com/181... so I think the src of the photo. Do you have any attempts for a solution?